# Is there a more intuitive proof that a 1-planar graph with minimum degree 7 contains a $K_4$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

In the following paper, Hudák Dávid, and Tomáš Madaras give the following Theorem 1.1.

- Hudák, Dávid, and Tomáš Madaras. "On local properties of 1-planar graphs with high minimum degree." Ars Mathematica Contemporanea 4.2 (2011): 245-254.

**Theorem 1.1.** Each 1-planar graph of minimum degree 7 contains

a) a pair of adjacent 7-vertices,

b) a copy of $K_4$ with all vertices of degree at most 13,

c) a copy of $K_{2,3}^*$ with all vertices of degree at most 13 ,

d) a copy of $W_5$ with all vertices of degree at most 11.

The authors mainly use **the charging and discharging method** to prove that a 1-planar graph with minimum degree 7 contains certain structures. I will use b) to illustrate, and excerpt the proof of theorem b).

> **Proof of Theorem 1.1b).** By contradiction. Suppose that there exists a 1-planar graph $G$ of minimum degree 7 such that each its
> subgraph $K_4$ contains at least one $\geq 14$-vertex, called big;
> vertices of degrees between 7 and 13 are called intermediate. We
> proceed with the Discharging Method with the initial charge assignment
> (2); the initial charges are redistributed according to following
> rules:
>
> **Rule 1:** Each $\geq$ 4-face $\alpha \in F^{\times}$redistributes its initial charge uniformly among incident 4-vertices.
>
> **Rule 2:** Each intermediate vertex sends $\frac{1}{7}$ to each adjacent 4-vertex.
>
> **Rule 3:** Let $[x y z]$ be a 3-face of $G^{\times}, x$ be a 4-vertex and $y$ be an intermediate vertex. Then $y$ sends additional
> $\frac{1}{14}$ to $x$.
>
> **Rule 4:** Each big vertex sends $\frac{4}{7}$ to each adjacent 4-vertex.
>
> **Rule 5:** Let $[x y z]$ be a 3-face of $G^{\times}, x$ be a 4-vertex and $y$ be a big vertex. Then $y$ sends additional $\frac{2}{7}$ to
> $x$.
>
> We check the nonnegativity of final charges of vertices and faces of
> $G^{\times}$. From the formulation of discharging rules, it is easy to
> see that the final charge of all faces is nonnegative. Thus, it is
> enough to analyze just the final charge of vertices.
>
> **Case 1:** Let $x$ be a 4-vertex of $G^{\times}$. If $x$ is incident with at least two $\geq 4$-faces, then, by Rule $1, c^*(x) \geq-2+2
> > \cdot \frac{2 \cdot 4-6}{2}=-2+2 \cdot 1=0$. If $x$ is incident with
> exactly one $\geq 4$-face, then, by Rules 1, 2 and 3 (or, eventually,
> 1, 4 and 5) we obtain the estimation $c^*(x) \geq-2+\frac{2 \cdot
> > 4-6}{2}+4 \cdot \frac{1}{7}+6 \cdot \frac{1}{14}=0$. Finally, if $x$
> is incident only with 3 -faces, then its neighbours in
> $G^{\times}$induce a $K_4$, hence, one of them is big; then, by Rules
> 2,3,4 and 5, we obtain $c^*(x) \geq-2+3 \cdot \frac{1}{7}+6 \cdot
> > \frac{1}{14}+\frac{4}{7}+2 \cdot \frac{2}{7}=0$.
>
> **Case 2:** Let $x$ be an intermediate $d$-vertex of $G^{\times}$. Then $c^*(x) \geq d-6-d \cdot \frac{1}{7} \geq 0$ for $d \geq 7$.
>
> **Case 3:** Let $x$ be a big $d$-vertex of $G^{\times}$. Then $c^*(x) \geq d-6-d \cdot \frac{4}{7} \geq 0$ for $d \geq 14$.

The charging and discharging method is very clever, but also very elusive. I really can't think of an intuitive reason why a 1-planar graph with minimum degree 7 must contain $K_4$.

Do we have any hope of proving this fact without using the charging and discharging method?